# What is the meaning of this samurai crest?

Tags: japan, heraldry, samurai, medieval-japan

From User Jordan Miles Hamanaka Kaplowit's comment to this question: [Meaning of samurai crest / symbol](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14178/meaning-of-samurai-crest-symbol)

[image]

What is the meaning of the sixth crest symbol?

Comment: catnip for semaphore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That appears to be a `maru-ni-mitsu-kashiwa` (丸に三つ柏) crest, also known as a `maru-ni-makino-kashiwa` (丸に牧野柏). It is an encircled, three-leafed version of the `kashiwa` crest designs, one of the Big Ten styles of crests. These crests features an underlying design derived from the leaf of a [Daimyo Oak tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_dentata).

In Winter, dead leafs of a *Quercus dentata* tree do not fall until new ones starts to grow in Spring. Thus, since ancient times the *kashiwa* has symbolised the **continuity**, or the **propagation of the family** through generations . These are appealing elements in Japanese culture, which has historically placed great importance on perpetuating familial lineages.

As is usually the case with the more plain designs, the `maru-ni-mitsu-kashiwa` has been used by many clans. The most closely associated is probably the ancient [**Makino** clan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makino_clan), who even lent their names to the crest. But several other families used this too, including the `Kasahara`, the `Nagae`, and the `Kuriyama`. One notable user was [**Shima Sakon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shima_Sakon), a retainer of [Ishida Mitsunari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishida_Mitsunari). He was famed for being hired with a ridiculous salary (half of Ishida's land's income), and for fighting with ferocious bravery in the fatal [Battle of Sekigahara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Sekigahara).

In addition, there exists a huge range of different `kashiwa` crest designs. Here are some examples:

[image][image][image][image][image]

From left to right:

- **the `mitsu-kashiwa` crest**, an un-circled version used by the [**Kasai**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasai_clan) of [Mutsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutsu_Province).
- **the `maru-ni-tosa-kashiwa` (丸に土佐柏) crest**, thinned version used by the [**Yamauchi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamauchi_clan) of [Tosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosa_Province)
- **the `tsuru-gashiwa` (蔓柏) crest**, a veined version used by the [**Unomiya Shrine** (鸕宮神社)](http://www.genbu.net/data/iga/umiya_title.htm)
- **the `daki-gashiwa` (抱き柏) crest**, used by the **`Hiromine`**, priests of [Hiromine Shrine](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BA%83%E5%B3%AF%E7%A5%9E%E7%A4%BE)
- **the `chigai-kashiwa` (違い柏) crest**, a crossed version used by the [**Kanou**](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A0%E7%B4%8D%E6%B0%8F) of [Ichinomiya Han](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichinomiya_Domain)

<sub>(I'm only naming one as an example for each; in fact there could be dozens more different clans/shrines using the same crest.)</sub>

Moreso than samurais, however, the `kashiwa` designs are as a group **very popular among [Shinto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinto) organisations**, including both the shrines themselves and priestly clans. This is due to the Daimyo Oak tree being historically regarded as a holy tree; its large and study leafs a traditional (and literally green!) food container for making offerings to the gods.

A vestige of this use might be the [*kashiwa mochi* (柏餅)], a [*wagashi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagashi) consisting of rice cakes wrapped in Daimyo Oak leafs, which continues to be eaten for the [Dragon Boat Festival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duanwu_Festival).

[image]

Comment: Re: the proposed edit, I'm saying the Hiromine *family* used the oak crest (see - http://www2.harimaya.com/sengoku/html/hiromine.html). I don't know which tripadvisor image you're referring to, but chrysanthemum crests are imperial. On some photos you can see the Hiromine *temple* uses something similar to the oak crests on the left, and another crest on the right. That one's called a papaya crest.