# Katabami mon (Japanese crests of wood sorrel) Crest family identity

Tags: medieval-japan

I am hoping to narrow my search for this family crest from two caskets A pair of Edo Period Hokai Kaiawase Lacquer Chests. I have found (with the help of History Stack) a Mon which may be the one. Maruni Katabami is close to my version. 
[Edo period Family Mon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIgjq.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIgjq.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I looked at other requests for family mons (as suggested by the help section) and found this excellent lengthy discussion on Family crests with lots of links and description. This answer led me to the information I am looking for. Thank you, Semaphore♦ and Tyler Durden and user64617! [Meaning of samurai crest / symbol](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14178/meaning-of-samurai-crest-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1)