# What can I learn about family crest number 11?

Tags: medieval-japan

Hello I am trying to find out some information on this family crest:

[image]

Is this crest related to [this mon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%8Dgoku_Takatsugu)?

I have a full samurai suit of armor with this mark.

Comment: Which one is number 11? Is there nothing at all further about it that you know, such as it's name or description in Japanese?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/21135/24858) to the older question on History:SE (_Meaning of samurai crest / symbol_) answer your question?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It is the four dotted squares (rotated in a big circle), which is also illustrated at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Maruni_sumitate_yotsume.svg and may be related to the *mon* at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%8Dgoku_Takatsugu

Comment: **Please** add that to the question; it is really not the done thing to ask people to read the comment string to understand your question. (Apologies to @Henry - I had a senior moment and misread the attribution; I still think the information should be in the question.)

Comment: I know nothing about Japanese clans so this is solely what I was able to dig up.  But I think it could have belonged to the Teramura clan.  See this Japanese wikipedia page (use the translate) to get more information.  https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AF%BA%E6%9D%91%E6%B0%8F